# LogonUser returns error code 2

Tags: c#, file, console-application, impersonation

I am trying just simple code that would copy file from local computer to remote server. The problem is that I am getting error code 2 from logonUser function and I have no idea why. I am not sure what to put as a domain (I have tried name of the local computer, empty string, localhost) since when I am e.g. mapping drives from that server I can do it just with userName and password.

Snippet of the code I am using is here:

```
public static void Impersonate(string domainName, string userName, string userPassword, Action actionToExecute)
{
    SafeTokenHandle safeTokenHandle;
    try
    {
        //parametry pripojeni
        const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;
        const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;
        const int LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS = 9;
        //Ziskani ovladace k pristupovemu tokenu
        bool returnValue = LogonUser(userName, domainName, userPassword, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, out safeTokenHandle);
    }
    catch(Exception e) { ... }
}
```

returnValue is always false and error code 2. I would be glad for any advice what I might have been doing wrong...

Comment: Are these home PCs? Or running on a domain? Also, please outline your underestanding of what a domain is.

Comment: If it works via a mapping then you could just use WNetAddConnection2 to connect to the share path.

Comment: Currently I wanted to test file transfer from my computer to our "fileserver" where we have only one domain (when my understanding of domains is quite limited - I take it as a "group" of computers that are physically and logically interconnected). But next step is to use it at a customer that has multiple domains and it won´t be possible to use shared path...